# How to load external files (html,js,css) in kango framework

Tags: kango-framework

I am working on Kango framework. In which I am facing problem to fetch external files in kango framework (browser extension).

Comment: What's your use case you want to include html files for?

Answer (score 1):

**Background script:**

In the background script JavaScript files are included by adding them to `common/extension_info.json` like this:

```
{
    "background_scripts": [
        "foo.js",
        "main.js"
    ]
}
```

**Content script:**

In the content script JavaScript depndencies are added by adding a header annotation to the main file (the one declared as content script in `common/extension_info.json`):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @require foo.js
// ==/UserScript==

// do stuff here...
```

Kango does not provide a good way to add CSS files in the content script. This has to be done by adding (and possibly removing) a `<link>` tag to the `<head>` section:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', kango.io.getResourceUrl('foo.css'));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```